# As a Half-Open Interval, is [a,a) defined?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Simple question, hopefully a simple answer, is $[a,a)$, read as a half-open interval of real numbers, defined for $a \in \mathbb{R}$? My feeling would be that it's not, but I cannot find anywhere which explicitly addresses this.

Read as "The set of real numbers $x$ which satisfy $a \leq x < a$," there are no $x$ which satisfy the conditions, suggesting you can identify $[a,a) = \emptyset$, but I would think the "half-closed" part would indicate the set is specifically not empty and contains $a$, thus posing a problem with the open upper bound, giving $[a,a)$ as undefined. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't be disturbed by the generic notation. When developped, the (universally adopted) definition leads indeed to $[a,a) = \varnothing,$ a fact that is used in some proofs.

Comment: There's not really any clarification to be given. If your definition is "all $x$ such that $a \le x < a$," since no $x$ satisfies that, it is empty. If your definition is "all $x$ such that $x=a$ or $a<x<a$" (as your second guess ***sort of*** implies), then it is $\{a\}$. This is entirely about how you define it -- and you have to take that definition at face value and very literally, with no extra guesses as to what "might" be intended. That said, I've only ever seen the first one of these, and that the only case where $(a,a),(a,a],[a,a),[a,a]$ is nonempty would be the last, as $\{a\}$.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have an interval that includes $a$ and excludes $a$. You can translate $a \leq x < a$ as "$a \leq x$ and $x < a$", which is nonsense. After all, how can $a$ be less than or equal to $x$, and greater than $x$, at the same time?

Comment: @Accelerator $a \leq x < a$ excludes $a$ but does not include it. And it is not nonsense, it makes sense and just has the truth value "false", for any $x$. This is why the set is well defined and empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only reasonable interpretation is
$$[a,a) = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid a \le x < a \} = \emptyset . $$
However, in a comment PrincessEev suggests that there could be also an alternative definition of $[a,a)$ as
$$[a,a) = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid x = a \vee a < x < a \} = \{a\} . \tag{*}$$
But this would have some unwelcome consequences. In my opinion we should have some rules for union and intersection of intervals. If "$\langle$" denotes "$[$" or "$($" and "$\rangle$" denotes "$]$" or "$)$", we would expect for example

1. $\langle a,b] \cup [b,c \rangle = \langle a,c \rangle$
2. $\langle a,b) \cup [b,c \rangle = \langle a,c \rangle$
3. $\langle a,b] \cup (b,c \rangle = \langle a,c \rangle$
4. $\langle a,b) \cap (a,b \rangle = (a,b)$

Using (*) we would also have $(a,a] = \{a\}$, thus $(a,a) = (a,a] \cap [a,a) =\{a\}$ which does not make much sense. Also $\langle d,a) = \langle d,a) \cup [a,a) = \langle d,a]$ is not what we expect.